# How can I run Scrapyd on a server

Tags: ubuntu, scrapy, scrapyd, scrapinghub

As of recently Scrapinghub no longer has periodic jobs in their free package, which is what I used to use to run my Scrapy crawlers.

Therefore, I decided to use [Scrapyd](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd) instead. So I went ahead and got a virtual server running Ubuntu 16.04. (This is my first time setting up and running a server, so please bear with me)

Following the instructions on [scrapyd.readthedocs.io](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) I installed Scrapyd using pip:

```
$ pip install scrapyd
```

(That was after I figured out that the recommended way for Ubuntu, using apt-get, is actually no longer supported, see [Github](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/252)).

Then I log onto my server using SSH, and run Scrapyd by simply running

```
$ scrapyd
```

Everything looks fine as far as I can tell:

```
2017-10-30 17:31:19+0000 [-] Log opened.
2017-10-30 17:31:19+0000 [-] twistd 16.0.0 (/usr/bin/python 2.7.12) starting up.
2017-10-30 17:31:19+0000 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
2017-10-30 17:31:19+0000 [-] Site starting on 6800
2017-10-30 17:31:19+0000 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site instance at 0x7f644752bfc8>
2017-10-30 17:31:19+0000 [Launcher] Scrapyd 1.2.0 started: max_proc=4, runner=u'scrapyd.runner'
```

I would expect to see a web interface (described [here](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#webui)) when I go to my IP at http://82.165.102.18:6800.

Instead, I just get the error message "This site can’t be reached 82.165.102.18 refused to connect."

When I try to run Scrapyd locally, everything works just fine, and I get the web interface at http://localhost:6800/.

I have tried disabling the Firewall (UFW), but that didn't help.

At this point, I am lost. If you have any ideas, please let me know!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question might belong in a meta thread, but is soliciting allowed in comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can reach your Scrapyd instance locally but not over network, I suspect Scrapyd listens only on localhost. Be sure to have this line in your [`scrapyd.conf`](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html):

```
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

It instructs Scrapyd to listen on all interfaces. `bind_address` defaults to `127.0.0.1`, so by default it only listens on localhost.

Comment: Thanks a million, Tomas, that was it!

Comment: By the way: I had to create the file scrapyd.conf, as it didn't exist before. I created the file taking [this example file](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html#example-configuration-file) as a template and changed the bind_address as you suggested.

Comment: Also, I didn't mention it the last time, but consider running Scrapyd in Docker. It greatly simplifies things, especially if deploy in scale.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, Tomas. Do you think you could maybe have a look at my follow-up question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065225/preferred-way-to-run-scrapyd-in-the-background-as-a-service)?

Comment: I had the same problem on Vultr, and I had to open the port with ufw for it to work. 
```bash
ufw allow 6800
```